Shuffling data before createDataPartition in R
I’m using a Random Forest model on my dataset to evaluate how well the features are differentiating between my classes. The first 59 rows of my data are labeled “Normal” and the last 17 rows are labeled “Cancer.” I’m wondering if I need to shuffle the rows before splitting the data into training and testing sets using createDataPartition().
For example:
#Shuffle the data
df <- df[sample(nrow(df)),]

# Split data into training and testing sets
train_index <- createDataPartition(y = df$Class, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)

I’m unsure if createDataPartition automatically shuffles the data, or if I should manually shuffle the data to ensure that my partitions are representative of each class label.

Why don’t you try it and see?
